# Will cloudflare cache things by default?

Tags: cloudflare

The help section of Caching -> Configuration -> Caching Level says:

> Note: By default, Cloudflare does not cache HTML content. You can create a Page Rule to cache static HTML content.

I have no page rules set yet. But when I goto Analytics, I see there are 600+ cached requests. Anybody know what happened here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the note says "By default, Cloudflare does not cache HTML content.". That means your .html files are not cached but other assets like images, javascript or fonts are.

Here a list of filetypes that will be cached by default:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior#default-cached-file-extensions